# error TRK0005: Failed to locate: "CL.exe"

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, npm

I'm using Windows 8.1. I installed Visual Studio 2015 community edition.  When I run npm install -g generator-keystone, I get the error at the bottom.  I tried running the following commands, but I'm still getting the same results.

```
set GYP_MSVS_VERSION=2015
npm config set msvs_version 2015 --global


C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\generator-keystone\node_modules\buffertools>if not defined npm_config_no
de_gyp (node "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node
-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node  rebuild )
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(366,5): warning MSB8003: Could not fi
nd WindowsSDKDir variable from the registry.  TargetFrameworkVersion or PlatformToolset may be set to an invalid versio
n number. [C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\generator-keystone\node_modules\buffertools\build\buffertool
s.vcxproj]
TRACKER : error TRK0005: Failed to locate: "CL.exe". The system cannot find the file specified. [C:\Users\user\AppData
\Roaming\npm\node_modules\generator-keystone\node_modules\buffertools\build\buffertools.vcxproj]


gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib
\build.js:270:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.3.9600
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm
\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\generator-keystone\node_modules\buffertools
gyp ERR! node -v v4.2.2
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN install:buffertools@2.1.3 buffertools@2.1.3 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm WARN install:buffertools@2.1.3 Exit status 1
C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm
├── generator-keystone@0.3.9
└── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY yo@>=1.0.0
```

Answer (score 71, accepted):

I went into Visual Studio and created a Visual C++ project, which installed several libraries.  npm install worked after that.

Comment: That's all you did? No specifics, just create a C++ project first?

Comment: @JoshuaDannemann. Short answer: **Yes**, then click ok to install default selected option. If you create a new C++ project then main frame would show you 2 options for Install extra packages. That packages are `Common tools for Visual C++ 2015` and includes the Compiler wich is not enabled (nor downloaded) by default in the Visual Studio 2015 setup. Also installs the Win8.1 SDK.U can take a deeper look here http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=691132

Comment: I had installed VS 2015 only thinking I had to ensure web tools were installed - reading this comment prompted me to go back and ensure I had also installed Visual C++. I was able to run npm install with node-gyp for a yeoman angular-generator no problem after :) Did not need to create a C++ project, however.

Comment: Genius advise, it helped! Thanks a lot.

Comment: I confirm that issue is fixed after re-run VS 2015 setup -> apply offered updates -> installed both **Common tools for Visual C++ 2015** and **Windows 10 SDK**. In my case it failed while trying to do: npm install -g buffertools. Now all is ok.

Comment: @FinbarMaginn blaming the operating system is easy, but don't you think the blame should be on **node-gyp**? node-gyp is supposed to be a utility to invoke the c++ compiler, but it was apparently not tested enough in the windows environment.

Comment: I can sympathise with both @Fin

Comment: After trying for days and testing 100s and 100s of answers. This is what finally worked. Great answer. It may often be the last working answer for this windows environment issue straight from hell !

Comment: 5 years later, and this nonsense is still the same. Blew the winds out of my sails.

Answer (score 6):

I went to `\Users\[my-user]\.windows-build-tools` - an install file for VS Build-tools was there (for 2017 it's `vs_BuildTools.exe`), I ran and installed it.

After that I ran `npm install --global --production windows-build-tools` 
("Option 1" from [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp)).

Then it worked.

Comment: npm install --global --production windows-build-tools worked for me

Answer (score 0):

If your project is very old, try a different platform.  In one case I changed Project -> Properties -> Platform Toolset from Windows XP to a newer platform, then picked Rebuild Solution.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow `cl.exe` was missing from my `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\Hostx64\x64` folder. I had to delete and reinstall `buildtools` using the installer.

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't have 50 reputation I can't comment to a couple of the questions on here.

1. The bin folder that one of the posters is referring to is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin" this could be different for other users based on what version of Visual Studio you have installed on your system. Guessing that they are just putting msbuild on the PATH without more information.
2. Another poster put that they changed 140 to 142 and it worked. They are talking about the "PlatformToolset" version in the vcxproj file. The reason this fix worked for them is that they have Visual Studio 2019 and the vcxproj file was set up to build on Visual Studio 2015. If they are working with other people and push their project the next person to pull it could have the same issue if they are using a different version of Visual Studio than 2019.

Answer (score -1):

I use visual basic 2019 latest version. Couldn't run a project with toolset 140. Insted it pops the message TRK0005: Failed to locate: CL.exe. I change it to 142 and it works.

Comment: change what to 142?  Where?  How?

Answer (score -2):

For me this problem was solved after including bin folder in the windows environment variable

Comment: what bin folder?  What variable?  How?