# NPM install error Failed to locate: "CL.exe". The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: npm, npm-install

I am on Win 10, NPM 6.14.8, Node 11.15.0
I get a project which throws me an error on npm install. It is log error log and I am lost in it. I had many other projects and non o them have a problem with npm install. Can somebody tell me please what is the problem in this case? Here is console log:

```
c:\wamp64-3-2-0\www\hoom-backend\node_modules\tomahawk\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-l
ifecycle\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )                                      
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.                                                                                                               
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(366,5): warning MSB8003: Could not find WindowsSDKDir variable from the registry.  Ta                                                   
rgetFrameworkVersion or PlatformToolset may be set to an invalid version number. [c:\wamp64-3-2-0\www\hoom-backend\node_modules\tomahawk\node_modules\socket.io\node_mo                                                   
dules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\build\bufferutil.vcxproj]                                                                                                                                                                 
TRACKER : error TRK0005: Failed to locate: "CL.exe". The system cannot find the file specified. [c:\wamp64-3-2-0\www\hoom-backend\node_modules\tomahawk\node_modules\so                                                   
cket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\build\bufferutil.vcxproj]                                                                                                                                                  
                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(366,5): warning MSB8003: Could not find WindowsSDKDir variable from the registry.  Ta                                                   
rgetFrameworkVersion or PlatformToolset may be set to an invalid version number. [c:\wamp64-3-2-0\www\hoom-backend\node_modules\tomahawk\node_modules\socket.io\node_mo                                                   
dules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\build\validation.vcxproj]                                                                                                                                                                 
TRACKER : error TRK0005: Failed to locate: "CL.exe". The system cannot find the file specified. [c:\wamp64-3-2-0\www\hoom-backend\node_modules\tomahawk\node_modules\so                                                   
cket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\build\validation.vcxproj]                                                                                                                                                  
                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
> ws@0.4.31 install c:\wamp64-3-2-0\www\hoom-backend\node_modules\tomahawk\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws                                             
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)                                                                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
c:\wamp64-3-2-0\www\hoom-backend\node_modules\tomahawk\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodej
s\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild ) 
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.                                                                                                               
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(366,5): warning MSB8003: Could not find WindowsSDKDir variable from the registry.  Ta                                                   
rgetFrameworkVersion or PlatformToolset may be set to an invalid version number. [c:\wamp64-3-2-0\www\hoom-backend\node_modules\tomahawk\node_modules\socket.io\node_mo                                                   
dules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws\build\bufferutil.vcxproj]                                                                                                                            
TRACKER : error TRK0005: Failed to locate: "CL.exe". The system cannot find the file specified. [c:\wamp64-3-2-0\www\hoom-backend\node_modules\tomahawk\node_modules\so                                                   
cket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws\build\bufferutil.vcxproj]                                                                                                             
                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(366,5): warning MSB8003: Could not find WindowsSDKDir variable from the registry.  Ta                                                   
rgetFrameworkVersion or PlatformToolset may be set to an invalid version number. [c:\wamp64-3-2-0\www\hoom-backend\node_modules\tomahawk\node_modules\socket.io\node_mo                                                   
dules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws\build\validation.vcxproj]                                                                                                                            
TRACKER : error TRK0005: Failed to locate: "CL.exe". The system cannot find the file specified. [c:\wamp64-3-2-0\www\hoom-backend\node_modules\tomahawk\node_modules\so                                                   
cket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws\build\validation.vcxproj]                                                                                                             
                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
> iltorb@2.4.5 install c:\wamp64-3-2-0\www\hoom-backend\node_modules\iltorb                                                                                                                                               
> node ./scripts/install.js || node-gyp rebuild                                                                                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
info looking for cached prebuild @ C:\Users\vladi\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_prebuilds\0a16f1-iltorb-v2.4.5-node-v67-win32-x64.tar.gz                                                                                     
http request GET https://github.com/nstepien/iltorb/releases/download/v2.4.5/iltorb-v2.4.5-node-v67-win32-x64.tar.gz                                                                                                      
http 404 https://github.com/nstepien/iltorb/releases/download/v2.4.5/iltorb-v2.4.5-node-v67-win32-x64.tar.gz                                                                                                              
WARN install No prebuilt binaries found (target=11.15.0 runtime=node arch=x64 libc= platform=win32)                                                                                                                       
                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
c:\wamp64-3-2-0\www\hoom-backend\node_modules\iltorb>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.
js" rebuild )  else (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )                                                                                                      
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.                                                                                                               
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(366,5): warning MSB8003: Could not find WindowsSDKDir variable from the registry.  Ta                                                   
rgetFrameworkVersion or PlatformToolset may be set to an invalid version number. [c:\wamp64-3-2-0\www\hoom-backend\node_modules\iltorb\build\iltorb.vcxproj]                                                              
TRACKER : error TRK0005: Failed to locate: "CL.exe". The system cannot find the file specified. [c:\wamp64-3-2-0\www\hoom-backend\node_modules\iltorb\build\iltorb.vcxp                                                   
roj]                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
gyp ERR! build error                                                                                                                                                                                                      
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\MSBuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1                                                                                                                      
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:194:23)                                                                                            
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:193:13)                                                                                                                                                                
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:255:12)                                                                                                                              
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18362                                                                                                                                                                                     
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"                                                                 
gyp ERR! cwd c:\wamp64-3-2-0\www\hoom-backend\node_modules\iltorb                                                                                                                                                         
gyp ERR! node -v v11.15.0                                                                                                                                                                                                 
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0                                                                                                                                                                                               
gyp ERR! not ok                                                                                                                                                                                                           
npm WARN rollback Rolling back readable-stream@3.6.0 failed (this is probably harmless): EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat 'c:\wamp64-3-2-0\www\hoom-backend\node_modules\bl\node_modules'                            
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for dns@0.2.2: wanted: {"node":">= 0.10.0 < 0.11.0"} (current: {"node":"11.15.0","npm":"6.14.8"})                                                                                      
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: dns@0.2.2                                                                                                                                                   
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for watchpack-chokidar2@2.0.0: wanted: {"node":"<8.10.0"} (current: {"node":"11.15.0","npm":"6.14.8"})                                                                                 
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: watchpack-chokidar2@2.0.0                                                                                                                                   
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@~2.1.2 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):                                                                                                            
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})                                                         
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.2.7 (node_modules\watchpack-chokidar2\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):                                                                           
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})                                                        
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for tomahawk@0.1.6: wanted: {"node":">= 0.8.0 < 0.11.0"} (current: {"node":"11.15.0","npm":"6.14.8"})                                                                                  
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: tomahawk@0.1.6                                                                                                                                              
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for hawk@0.10.2: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x"} (current: {"node":"11.15.0","npm":"6.14.8"})                                                                                                 
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: hawk@0.10.2                                                                                                                                                 
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for hoek@0.7.6: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x"} (current: {"node":"11.15.0","npm":"6.14.8"})                                                                                                  
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: hoek@0.7.6                                                                                                                                                  
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for boom@0.3.8: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x"} (current: {"node":"11.15.0","npm":"6.14.8"})                                                                                                  
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: boom@0.3.8                                                                                                                                                  
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for cryptiles@0.1.3: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x"} (current: {"node":"11.15.0","npm":"6.14.8"})                                                                                             
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: cryptiles@0.1.3                                                                                                                                             
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for sntp@0.1.4: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x"} (current: {"node":"11.15.0","npm":"6.14.8"})                                                                                                  
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: sntp@0.1.4                                                                                                                                                  
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.2.7 (node_modules\laravel-mix\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):                                                                                   
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})                                                        
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.2.7 (node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):                                                                            
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})                                                        
npm WARN material-icons-react@1.0.4 requires a peer of react@~0.14.8 || ^15.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.                                                                       
npm WARN material-icons-react@1.0.4 requires a peer of react-dom@~0.14.8 || ^15.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.                                                                   
npm WARN react-i18next@10.13.2 requires a peer of i18next@>= 17.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.                                                                                   
npm WARN react-select-plus@1.0.0-rc.3.patch12 requires a peer of react@^0.14 || ^15.0.0-rc || ^15.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.                                                   
npm WARN react-select-plus@1.0.0-rc.3.patch12 requires a peer of react-dom@^0.14 || ^15.0.0-rc || ^15.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.                                               
npm WARN react-input-autosize@1.1.0 requires a peer of react@^0.14 || ^15.0.0-rc || ^15.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.                                                             
npm WARN ajv-errors@1.0.1 requires a peer of ajv@>=5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.                                                                                              
npm WARN The package bootstrap is included as both a dev and production dependency.                                                                                                                                       
                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE                                                                                                                                                                                                  
npm ERR! errno 1                                                                                                                                                                                                          
npm ERR! iltorb@2.4.5 install: `node ./scripts/install.js || node-gyp rebuild`                                                                                                                                            
npm ERR! Exit status 1                                                                                                                                                                                                    
npm ERR!                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
npm ERR! Failed at the iltorb@2.4.5 install script.                                                                                                                                                                       
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:                                                                                                                                                                      
npm ERR!     C:\Users\vladi\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-09-02T09_34_33_573Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer helped to fix it [error TRK0005: Failed to locate: "CL.exe"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33716369/error-trk0005-failed-to-locate-cl-exe)

by command `npm install --global --production windows-build-tools`