# Error 1696 the system can not find the file specified

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFqkj.png)I am a new software student try to learning the concepts of programming , i downloaded visual studio 22 to start coding but i staked with this issue ; when i start run the program attached message appears and i could not figure where is the root cause of problem , Could any one can help me ?

[image]

A solution for the problem

Comment: Are you certain you installed C++ support? Open the installer and make sure "Desktop development with C++" is checked. There is no dedicated C support, it comes along with C++. `Int` is also incorrect, it should be `int`.

Comment: Try this solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62616834/vcruntime-h-missing-from-windows-include-folder

Comment: Not the first problem you need to solve but note that C is case sensitive. `Int` needs to be `int`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [error TRK0005: Failed to locate: "CL.exe"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33716369/error-trk0005-failed-to-locate-cl-exe)